# How to fix when grub no longer mounts the boot partition at start up?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, grub, boot-loader, dmraid

This system has a boot partition on a dm-raid device.

I updated the system by standard methods from an older Ubuntu to the latest LTS. Now, if the kernel is updated by "apt-get upgrade", the new kernel will not load. Nor are the entries listed in the GRUB boot screen.

I have determined that update-grub works as I would expect, updating the partition mounted at /boot. However, when I boot it, GRUB reads the root drive /boot folder. It does not mount the raid isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p1 to /boot before starting up.

If I copy the contents of the mounted /boot drive to a folder, then unmount it and copy all the contents to the root drive /boot folder, the system will then boot the new kernels and show all the updates in the GRUB menu.

I need help to make sure GRUB will mount the raid based boot partition.

Next are some output from boot-repair tool.

```
 Boot Info Script e7fc706 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 23Nov2014]

============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

    Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p1 840df97f-7154-49a3-aa9c-02bd092d416c   ext2       
/dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p5 M9ln25-ua43-3S0c-xWeT-8Ejd-tk2U-kp5nNG LVM2_member 
/dev/mapper/server01-root c16300cf-e8da-4e2b-b34a-45d8fc12fb44   ext4       
/dev/mapper/server01-swap_1 b67b89f9-a131-46f8-b29b-0eb450e18a6a   swap       
/dev/sda                                                isw_raid_member 
/dev/sdb                                                isw_raid_member 
/dev/sdc1        08652f68-2f8e-4044-8c0b-9b33cb623bba   ext4       

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 19 23:21 ata-OCZ-VERTEX_30565XA328O39Y3Y2A6G -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 19 23:21 ata-OCZ-VERTEX_OH43J28TQB2Q7T570144 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 19 23:21 ata-WDC_WD20EARS-00MVWB0_WD-WCAZA1927955 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 19 23:11 ata-WDC_WD20EARS-00MVWB0_WD-WCAZA1927955-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 19 23:11 dm-name-isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0 -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 19 23:21 dm-name-isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p1 -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 19 23:21 dm-name-isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p2 -> ../../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 19 23:11 dm-name-isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p5 -> ../../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 19 23:21 dm-name-server01-root -> ../../dm-4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 19 23:21 dm-name-server01-swap_1 -> ../../dm-5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 19 23:11 dm-uuid-DMRAID-isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0 -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 19 23:21 dm-uuid-LVM-P3d2Ucn1G9Wx7NUE0e5vNgabXjXrfHIe555TD7gDdpyqH82c1sP9ofmm1Ook2SIS -> ../../dm-4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 19 23:21 dm-uuid-LVM-P3d2Ucn1G9Wx7NUE0e5vNgabXjXrfHIeA3DF0518wh8WsbW9i1cbOrcywyAwRUAg -> ../../dm-5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 19 23:21 dm-uuid-part1-DMRAID-isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0 -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 19 23:21 dm-uuid-part2-DMRAID-isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0 -> ../../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 19 23:11 dm-uuid-part5-DMRAID-isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0 -> ../../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 19 23:21 raid-isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0-part1 -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 19 23:21 raid-isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0-part2 -> ../../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 19 23:11 raid-isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0-part5 -> ../../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 19 23:21 wwn-0x50014ee2052521f1 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 19 23:11 wwn-0x50014ee2052521f1-part1 -> ../../sdc1

========================= "ls -R /dev/mapper/" output: =========================

/dev/mapper:
control
isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0
isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p1
isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p2
isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p5
server01-root
server01-swap_1

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p1 /boot                    ext2       (rw)
/dev/mapper/server01-root /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdc1        /home/backup/repos       ext4       (rw)


=========================== server01-root/etc/fstab: ============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#                
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/server01-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p1 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/server01-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/scd0       /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
UUID=08652f68-2f8e-4044-8c0b-9b33cb623bba   /home/backup    ext4    defaults    0   2   

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

========= Devices which don't seem to have a corresponding hard drive: =========

{All_DMRaid} 

=================== os-prober:
/dev/mapper/server01-root:The OS now in use - Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS CurrentSession:linux

=================== blkid:
/dev/sda: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/sdb: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p1: UUID="840df97f-7154-49a3-aa9c-02bd092d416c" TYPE="ext2"
/dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p5: UUID="M9ln25-ua43-3S0c-xWeT-8Ejd-tk2U-kp5nNG" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/server01-root: UUID="c16300cf-e8da-4e2b-b34a-45d8fc12fb44" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/server01-swap_1: UUID="b67b89f9-a131-46f8-b29b-0eb450e18a6a" TYPE="swap"

[dmraid -sa -c] isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0
Set sda as corresponding disk of mapper/server01-root

1 disks with OS, 1 OS : 1 Linux, 0 MacOS, 0 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.

Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.

sfdisk: ERROR: sector 500734 does not have an msdos signature
Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.
Warning: invalid flag 0x616f of partition table 5 will be corrected by w(rite)
Warning: invalid flag 0x616f of partition table 5 will be corrected by w(rite)

=================== /etc/grub.d/ :
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root        4096 Oct 21 10:25 grub.d
total 76
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9761 Oct 28 09:08 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6058 May  8  2014 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11608 Nov  3 18:39 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10412 May 15  2014 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1992 Mar 12  2014 20_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11692 May 15  2014 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1416 May 15  2014 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Oct  6  2010 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 May 15  2014 41_custom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   483 Oct  6  2010 README

=================== /etc/default/grub :

# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

/boot detected in the fstab of mapper/server01-root: /dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p1  (mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p1)

=================== mapper/server01-root/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf :
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST 

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY metadata=imsm UUID=a624f30e:6036d720:067d7817:ea238d58
ARRAY /dev/md/Volume0 container=a624f30e:6036d720:067d7817:ea238d58 member=0 UUID=03fe4a37:77503687:17ce6055:d75a6ac2

=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:
mapper/server01-root    : sdb,  .
mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p1 : mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0,    /boot.
sdb : not-GPT,  BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     not-usb,    has-os, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : not-GPT,  BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     not-usb,    no-os,  2048 sectors * 512 bytes
mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0   : not-GPT,  BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     not-usb,    no-os,  2048 sectors * 512 bytes

=================== mount:
/dev/mapper/server01-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)

=================== ls:
Disk /dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
fdisk: unable to read /dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p2: Inappropriate ioctl for device

=================== df -Th:
Filesystem                           Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/server01-root             ext4      225G  209G  4.7G  98% /
/dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p1 ext2      229M  123M   94M  57% /boot
/dev/sdc1                            ext4      1.8T  573G  1.2T  33% /home/backup

=================== fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00087dad

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1             512      500223      249856   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          500734   500130303   249814785    5  Extended
/dev/sda5   ?   809621278  1718751574   454565148+  32  Unknown

Disk /dev/sdb: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x99e561ed

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0: 256.1 GB, 256066715648 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31131 cylinders, total 500130304 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00087dad

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p1             512      500223      249856   83  Linux
/dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p2          500734   500130303   249814785    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p5          500736   500130303   249814784   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p1: 255 MB, 255852544 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31 cylinders, total 499712 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Partition outside the disk detected.


=================== Suggested repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge 
(in order to enable-raid enable-lvm) and reinstall the 
grub2 of mapper/server01-root into the MBR of sdb, using 
the following options:
        mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p1/boot,
The boot flag would be placed on sdc1.
Additional repair would be performed:
        unhide-bootmenu-10s


=================== Advice in case of suggested repair
Warning: continuing without internet would leave your system 
unbootable. Please connect internet.
Do you want to continue?


=================== Final advice in case of suggested repair
Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sdb (128GB) disk!


=================== User settings
The settings chosen by the user will not act on the boot.
```

I am not sure of the suggestions.

```
The boot flag would be placed on sdc1.
```

sdc1 is a backup disk, it will not be there always. I don't need a boot setup on that disk I think.

I am worried it may become unbootable. This boot-repair requires internet, but that server will not be accessing the internet.

So, I ask you to share some grub commands to do the other steps:

```
 purge and reinstall the grub2 of mapper/server01-root into the MBR of sdb, using the following options:
    mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0p1/boot,
 Additional repair would be performed:
    unhide-bootmenu-10s
```

Answer (score 1):

This is described on the Ubuntu wiki. Maybe should have asked over there in first place. Sorry. But in case for future visitors. Here is [the link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_Terminal_Commands). However, the raid configuration did not allow installation on a /dev/sdb as indicated by boot-repair. The install must go to the main raid volume. Here is [another link](http://trisquel.info/en/forum/trisquel-doesnt-boot-anymore-after-upgrading-belenos#comment-58774) about that.

And here the short version:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge grub-common
sudo apt-get install grub-pc  #Choose /dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/mapper/isw_dbbbejgeca_Volume0
```